# c# word 2016 interop watermark Shapes.AddTextEffect ends in error

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I have used this code several times but with newer word Version it crashes on the position of Shapes.AddTextEffect:

```
    private void AddWatermarkToDocument(string sText, float fTextSize)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape logoWatermark = null;

        //Word.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader;
        try
        {
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in wordDoc.Sections)
            {
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeaderFooter hdr in section.Headers)
                {
                    if (hdr.Exists)
                    {
                        hdr.Range.Select();
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shapes shHeaders = hdr.Shapes;

                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application headerApp = wordDoc.Sections[1].Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages].Application;

                        logoWatermark = headerApp.ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextEffect(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, sText, "Arial", (float)60, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0,0, ref oMissing);


                //        logoWatermark = shHeaders.AddTextEffect(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffectMixed,
                //sText, "Arial", fTextSize, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0, 0,Type.Missing);

                        logoWatermark.Select(ref oMissing);

                        logoWatermark.Fill.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;

                        logoWatermark.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;

                        logoWatermark.Fill.Solid();
                        logoWatermark.Fill.BackColor.RGB = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);
                        logoWatermark.Fill.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
                        logoWatermark.Fill.Transparency = 0f;
                        logoWatermark.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
                        logoWatermark.Line.ForeColor.RGB = (Int32)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorRed;

                        logoWatermark.Top = (float)300; //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter; 
                        logoWatermark.Left = (float)10;

                        logoWatermark.Rotation = (float)-45;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }

    }
```

The text will be proceeded but ends in a exception - not set to an object...

Anyone with the same problem and a solution?

Comment: "Newer word version" - WHICH version?

Comment: Word 2016: Version 1804 Build 9226.2126

Comment: FWIW your code runs fine, here. I'm running Version 1806 (Build 10216.20000 Click-to-run). You don't show us how you instantiate `wordDoc`. Are you opening an existing file that might be damaged? Or working with a new document? If an existing file, try with a new document and see if the problem persists. Please also give more details about what you mean by "crash".